# Search uniqueidentifier value in SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, search, guid

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with `uniqueidentifier` field.

In my application (C#, WPF) I have a textbox which intended for search some data by GUID, user can enter guid by typing, ctrl+v, etc, so he/she can make an error.

What is the best and fastest approach to make a search by this field using linq2sql ignoring whitespaces, "-"... any other characters?

```
var d = from status in dc.FolderStatus.Where(status => status.Date <= DateTime.Now 
                    && status.Folder.TapeCode.ToString().Replace("-", "") == tapeCode.ToUpper().Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "")
                    )
```

`TapeCode` is `uniqueidentifier` in SQL Server 2008 and Guid in dbml file. Is it ok?

Comment: Please don't duplicate tags like (C#) in the title. Just leave them in the tags.

Comment: What's the first rule of a surrogate key? Never expose its values to end users!

Answer (score 3):

No, that will be extremely slow (it'll have to do a table scan, convert each identifier to a string and compare the string). Instead, you'll have to convert the input string to a `Guid` and compare that:

```
tapeCode = Regex.Replace(tapeCode, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
Guid id = Guid.Parse(tapeCode);
var d = from status in dc.FolderStatus
        where status.Date <= DateTime.Now 
           && status.Folder.TapeCode == id
        select status;
```

(Note that `Guid.Parse` method accepts 32 hexadecimal digits without dashes as a valid input).

Comment: (Note that Guid.Parse was introduced in .NET 4. Prior to that you had to call the constructor.)

Comment: @Jon: Oooooh, so that's why I couldn't find it in Reflector (to see whether it supported 32 hex digit format), I thought I was going mad :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `uniqueidentifier` field in SQL, I'd expect native support in LINQ to SQL. I believe you should be able to do:

```
Guid tapeCode = new Guid(text);
var d = from status in dc.FolderStatus
        where status.Date <= DateTime.Now && status.Folder.TapeCode == tapeCode
        select ...;
```

Now of course that will throw an exception if `text` doesn't represent a valid GUID. If you're using .NET 4, you can use [`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) in the same way you would for parsing integers etc:

```
Guid tapeCode;
if (Guid.TryParse(text, out tapeCode))
{
    var d = from status in dc.FolderStatus
            where status.Date <= DateTime.Now &&
                  status.Folder.TapeCode == tapeCode
            select ...;
}
else
{
    // Handle invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try and do .Replace on the SQL field, as this will actually get executed on the server, which is very slow.

You should massage the data coming in to your method.

I.e

```
public void GetFoo(string guid)
{
     string sqlGuid = guid.ToString().Trim().Replace("-", "");

     var d = from status in dc.FolderStatus.Where(status => status.Date <= DateTime.Now &&
                                                            status.Folder.TapeCode == sqlGuid);
}
```